# Loading a polygon based image on Snap.js

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am having difficulty loading a polygon based SVG image, in snap.svg.

Here is my

My HTML

```
<svg id="svgThing"></svg>
```

My JavaScript

```
var s = Snap("#svgThing");


Snap.load("/svgImage.svg", function (f) {
    g = f.selectAll("polygon");
    s.append(g);
});
```

And mysvg image code (part of it anyways it huge)

```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1440" height="758" style="display: block;"><polygon stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="1" stroke-width="1" points="721,-77 350,-77 679,-76" style="fill:#dcdb.............
```

Comment: Have you tried a select rather than a selectAll ?

Comment: I have tried select, but it just selects one of the polygons and doesnt, append anything on the page.

Comment: I have added the svg code that is at the beginning before the polygon starts not sure if that helps.

Comment: Can you put it on a fiddle to test ?